# CSS Display in Grid or table

Tags: html, css, grid, frontend

Hi Guys I need help displaying layout in CSS. Here is i want the layout to display like.

[image]

Here is what i have so far in CSS but can't get the menu zone to fully expand down height. Any suggestions? i'm using display grid as layout.

```css
.page{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:29% 71%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: start; 
}
.section-header{
 grid-column: 1/3;
 display:grid
 grid-row:row;
 background-color:blue;
 color:#fff;
}
.zone-menu-wrapper{
grid-row:1/3;
background-color:#286dc5;
}
.zone-topper-wrapper{
grid-row:1/3;
}
.section-main{
 grid-column:2/3;
 background-color:orange;
}
.section-footer{
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.zone-branding-wrapper{
  grid-column:2/3;
}

.zone-menu{
width:29%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
 <header class="section-header">
  <div class="zone-topper-wrapper">Top Zone</div>
  <div class="zone-menu-wrapper">Menu Zone</div>
 </header>
 <main class="section-main">
    <div class="zone-branding-wrapper">Branding Zone</div>
  <div class="zone-content-wrapper">Content Zone</div>
 </main>
 <footer class="section-footer">
  <div class="zone-footer-wrapper">Footer Zone</div>
 </footer>
</div>
</pre>
```

Comment: Did you try to CSS this markup?

Comment: FWIW, grid columns are [not that widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) yet.

Comment: I'd recommend using Flexbox, you can check the [Guide here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Hipady i tried using Flexbox but isn't that simple to display layout like that.

Comment: maybe you can use combination of width, height, position and float CSS properties to arrange your layout, they're basic properties and I think its pretty simple to use them

Comment: @AE86 not true at all. Flexbox can absolutely do the layout you want, so can old school floats.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `flexbox` solution that will give you greater support than `grid columns`. If you don't like flexbox you can always use a float based solution which would have even greater support.

I won't go into a lot of detail but the key takeaways are:

- `flex-grow`, tells the element to take up the remaining space of it's parent element. Very handy for stretching elements out to unknown widths, also flexible.
- `min-height: 100vh` in `body`, this allows the layout to take up the full viewport if their is not enough content to fill it. This also provides a context in which `flex-grow` can grow into. Without `min-height: 100vh;` flex-grow doesn't have any space to stretch elements out in.
- `100vh` for `min-height`, uses viewport units to establish the minimum height the `body` element can be. `100vh`, says use 100% of vertical height (`vh`) of viewport.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: indianred;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

header {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

aside {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>

<div class="wrap">

  <aside>
    Sidebar
  </aside>
  
  <div class="content">
  
    <main>
      Main
    </main>
    
    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the markup you have seems easier than mine. Can you try using flex on the markup i have?

Comment: I could but you're markup isn't that different. You should be able to modify things to your needs with minimal effort. I see a flaw in your markup in that it appears the sidebar on the left is contained within an element that it shouldn't be (based on your diagram).

Comment: @hungarstar i wish i could change the markup easier but since its a cms platform isn't difficult for me to control it. If you help me on the layout using the markup above i would be really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AE86 what element in your markup is supposed to be the sidebar on the left? From what I can see it probably isn't possible with your markup. Sometimes it's just not that easy and you'll have to get your hands dirty (make template changes in your CMS).

Comment: i wish i could change my markups but i do not have access to the backend files and access. So i only can layout for the markup i have currently.

Comment: Whelp, then you might be stuck and might have to rethink the layout you want to do given the markup you have.

Answer (score 1):

with grid, you may use just the minimal semantic markup needed:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 29% 71%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "nav main" "nav footer";
  height: 100vh
}

header {
  grid-area: header ;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav ;
  grid-column: 1;
}

main,
footer {
  grid-column: 2;/* or grid-area for each of them */
}

/*makup*/
header,
nav {
  background: tomato;
}

main {
  background: turquoise
}

footer {
  background: orange;
  }
body>* {
  padding:1em;
  box-shadow:0 0 1px
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<nav> nav </nav>
<main> main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="page">
    <header class="section-header">
        <div class="zone-topper-wrapper">Top Zone</div>

    </header>
  <div class="zone-menu-wrapper">Menu Zone</div>
    <main class="section-main">
    <div class="zone-branding-wrapper">Branding Zone</div>
        <div class="zone-content-wrapper">Content Zone</div>
    </main>
    <footer class="section-footer">
        <div class="zone-footer-wrapper">Footer<br> Zone</div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:29% 71%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: start; 
}
.section-header{
 grid-column: 1/3;
 display:grid
 grid-row:row;
 background-color:blue;
 color:#fff;
}
.zone-menu-wrapper{
grid-row:2/4;
background-color:#286dc5;
}
.zone-topper-wrapper{
grid-row:1/3;
}
.section-main{
 grid-column:2/3;
 background-color:orange;
}
.section-footer{
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.zone-branding-wrapper{
  grid-column:2/3;
}

.zone-menu{
width:29%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ak472526/pen/dvLaGX

Comment: This produces the same result the OP has in their question.

Comment: check change in HTML and CSS respectivally. check this codepen https://codepen.io/ak472526/pen/dvLaGX

Comment: Every element is on it's own row and doesn't replicate the diagram the OP has provided.